# Why does “Watchdog: BUG: Soft lockup CPU” errors occur when running openstack containers in docker

Tags: centos, docker, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I just deployed openstack using kolla and kolla-ansible stable/pike version. I deployed on one control node and one compute node. Both nodes are Dell PowerEdge 2950 servers that are running Centos 7. The deployment It worked but while I try to use the horizon dashboard, the control node is very slow and locks up and the terminal outputs the following:

```
Message from syslogd@openstackcontroller at Nov  7 21:46:39 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 23s! [runc:[2:INIT]:10527]

Message from syslogd@openstackcontroller at Nov  7 21:46:39 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#4 stuck for 23s! [fluentd:5005]

Message from syslogd@openstackcontroller at Nov  7 21:46:39 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#8 stuck for 23s! [keepalived:10664]

Message from syslogd@openstackcontroller at Nov  7 21:46:39 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#15 stuck for 23s! [java:5604]

Message from syslogd@openstackcontroller at Nov  7 21:46:39 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#5 stuck for 23s! [neutron-openvsw:3101]

Message from syslogd@openstackcontroller at Nov  7 21:46:39 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 23s! [cinder-schedule:3193]

Message from syslogd@openstackcontroller at Nov  7 21:46:39 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#7 stuck for 23s! [java:6186]

Message from syslogd@openstackcontroller at Nov  7 21:46:39 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#11 stuck for 23s! [docker-containe:6601]

Message from syslogd@openstackcontroller at Nov  7 21:46:39 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#12 stuck for 22s! [keepalived:4295]

Message from syslogd@openstackcontroller at Nov  7 21:46:39 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#10 stuck for 22s! [keepalived:10666]

Message from syslogd@openstackcontroller at Nov  7 21:46:39 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#9 stuck for 22s! [gmain:939]

Message from syslogd@openstackcontroller at Nov  7 21:46:39 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#13 stuck for 22s! [node:3261]

Message from syslogd@openstackcontroller at Nov  7 21:46:39 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 22s! [neutron-l3-agen:5071]

Message from syslogd@openstackcontroller at Nov  7 21:46:39 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#14 stuck for 22s! [irqbalance:898]
```

Whenever I stop all the docker containers that are running on the control node it seems to not have any more CPU lockup errors but as soon as I start up all the docker containers again that are running openstack services on the control node it starts to run very slow again and the lockup errors start again

Comment: What kernel are you running? Does the system recover properly when you stop the containers, or do you need to reboot to get it working again?

Comment: @RobbieCrash my kernel version is **3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64**. yes, I am able to shutdown all the containers which stops these errors from showing up on the terminal and the system can recover without rebooting.

Comment: What CPU/CPUs are you running this on?